Foreign romantic movie about a talented chef from 2005-2009
There's a really talented chef who lives alone. A female neighbour smells the food coming from his kitchen and is so drawn by it, she makes her way inside and tastes what he's cooking in a frying pan. He finds her, eating his food and she asks him what it is, he says, something like pigs testicles.
Later there's a scene where he comes to her house and cooks for her and her son. She has very little food in her house but he makes something with a coke sauce which is delicious... He is quite an austere character but is really passionate about the food.
No idea what the movie was called. It was either in German or French, but I think French.
The cover of this movie had a strawberry dipped in chocolate on a white background.

Sounds like Eden from 2006. From Rotten Tomatoes:

A chef discovers that the old saw "the way to a man's heart is through his stomach" works for women as well in this romantic comedy from Germany. Gregor (Josef Ostendorf) is a gourmet chef who runs a small but highly regarded restaurant in Berlin. [...] One night, Gregor meets Eden (Charlotte Roche), a woman who works as a waitress at a nearby resort hotel, and he's immediately smitten. However, Gregor soon discovers that Eden is married to Xaver (Devid Striesow) [...] Since seducing Eden would be out of the question, Gregor does what, for him, is the next best thing -- he cooks for her, starting with a special chocolate cake for her birthday, and following with a variety of special dishes that awaken her to the physical pleasures of life. 

You can see the trailer here, and here's the poster you described:

